# Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC) in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, wireless

how to add the Wireless Accessory Configuration (WAC)into the app and use the features. I am using this for the first time. Also tried find few tutorials for the same in google but was not successful. I need to know how to integrate that in my app and use the files of the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Configured in APP ID and enable Wireless Accessory Configuration